# How to turn on/off RequiredFieldValidator for radio button list in a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Essentially  I have a radio button list in a div element which is shown if the user email address is of a specific form i.e. ends in '@hotmail.com'.

If the div element is visible to the user then the RequiredFieldValidator should check that a radio button has been selected. If the div element is not shown then the RequiredFieldValidator shouldn't run.

This is my code so far:

```
 <div id="divPaymentMethod">
 <h5 class="right">Preferred Payment Method </h5>
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPaymentMethod" runat="server" CssClass="rbl" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Style="text-align:center; width:100%">
 <asp:ListItem Text="PayPal" Value="0" />
 <asp:ListItem Text="Invoicing" Value="1" />
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredPaymentMethod" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rblPaymentMethod" ErrorMessage="Please select a preferred payment method" ValidationGroup="CreateUser"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$().ready(function () {
           var element = $('[id$=UserName]');
           $(element).blur(function () {
               if ($(this).val().search(/@hotmail\.com$/) != -1) {
                   $('#divPaymentMethod').hide();
           }
           else {
                   $('#divPaymentMethod').show();
                }
           });
```

Is there another type of validator wich would be more suitable for this check? Or should I run the validation in the back end of my code? i.e. when the user submits their information the validation will be done and it will read through the state of the div element

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling and enabling the required Field Validator. Like so:

```
$().ready(function () {
       var element = $('[id$=UserName]');
       $(element).blur(function () {
           if ($(this).val().search(/@hotmail\.com$/) != -1) {
               $('#divPaymentMethod').hide();
               ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= RequiredPaymentMethod.ClientID %>'), false);

       }
       else {
               $('#divPaymentMethod').show();
               ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= RequiredPaymentMethod.ClientID %>'), true);
            }
       });
```

Comment: I've tried adding this but it still runs when the div is not shown unfortunately, which is stopping my from clicking the submit button

Comment: try changing the name to '<%=RequiredPaymentMethod.ClientID%>' for each enable.

Comment: This throws an error : The name 'RequiredPaymentMethod' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I just have but my code still wont run with the "<%=RequiredPaymentMethod %>. It doesn't recognise the elements. I have just tried to select the element via var payment = $('[id$=RequiredPaymentMethod]');

Comment: then use ValidatorEnable(payment, true);    But it still doesnt work

Comment: i know this may not be what you want but could you not use jquery validators? like in this example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/jquery-validation-with-Asp-Net-web-form/ its a lot easier enable and disable then.